# about JPA's transaction for create table and drop table with native query

Tags: jpa, transactions, nativequery

anyone can help me. this is a problem i've spent much
time on it. I'm using JTA'S BMT transaction, and I'm going to execute
3 steps in same transaction:

1. Insert one row to a table with entitymanager;
2. Drop a table if it exists with native query;
3. Create a table with native query; I wrote a wrong sql for native query in purpose, and rollbacked.

These 3 steps in same one transaction, but step 1 is always successful. I'm wondering if native query("drop table and create table") is not supported by JPA's transaction. Thank you guys in advance!! code like this:

```
try {
    tx.begin();
    table1 t1 = new table1();
    t1.setC1(c1);
    t1.setC2(c2);
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.persist(t1);
    Query query1= em.createNativeQuery("drop table if exists table2").executeUpdate();
    Query query2= em.createNativeQuery("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").executeUpdate();
    tx.commit();
    rt = true;
} catch (Exception e) {
    try {
        tx.rollback();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        PUB.log(e, PUB.getLineInfo());
    }
}
```

this is the declarations:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class MainSessionBean implements MainSessionBeanRemote {
    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "CC2016JPA2")
    static EntityManagerFactory emf;
    @Resource
    UserTransaction tx;
```

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `tx` ?  So why is the exact problem right now?

Comment: sorry, just wait a minute...i'll try to edit my question to add more code...

Comment: Sorry im not familiar yet here, because this is the first question in here!!

Comment: What is the exact problem you are having?

Comment: transaction doesn't work!! i executed a wrong sql:em.createNativeQuery("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").executeUpdate(); but em.persist(t1) is still successful, i rollbaked!